# RSS feed per tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, rss

Suppose stackoverflow.com wanted to have an **RSS feed per each tag**. They would probably have requests like stackoverflow.com/rss?tag=aspnet to return appropriate RSS feeds. This is the easy part.

Now when the user requested stackoverflow.com/rss?tag=aspnet he would see some XML. Instead it would be better to show a page where user can choose which RSS reader he wants to subscribe with (just like feedburner.com).

My question is: is there any ready-made code (html+javascript) that I can copy-paste to create such a subscription page? Basically I want to copy feedburner.com's subscription page onto my own site.

PS - I would be happy using feedburner.com, but it would require me to create a feed for each tag manually, which is impractical.